# pyqt model/view drag and drop:QAbstractItemModel::endMoveRows: Invalid index and QAbstractEventDispatcher: INTERNAL ERROR, timer ID 0 is too large

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt

I've got a pyqt implementation of `QTableView` and `QAbstractItemModel`.

In `QTableView` I've implemented Drag-and-Drop to allow user to drag rows with mouse by clicking on a cell and dragging it. `mousePressEvent`, `startDrag` and `dropEvent` functions are relevant to this process:

```
class View(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTableView.__init__(self, parent=None)
        #self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.MultiSelection)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.acceptDrops()
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos()
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        event.accept()
        if int(index.row()) != self.drag_row:
            try:
                self.model().moveRows(QModelIndex(), self.drag_row, self.drag_row, QModelIn
            except Exception as E:
                print E

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "mousePressEvent called"
        self.startDrag(event)
        super(View, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def startDrag(self, event):
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        self.moved_data = self.model().alignment.sequences[index.row()]

        drag = QDrag(self)

        mimeData = QMimeData()
        mimeData.setData("application/blabla", "")
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap = pixmap.grabWidget(self, self.visualRect(index))
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.drag_row = int(index.row())
```

Now, here is my model, which responds to drag, started in view with `mousePressEvent`, by `moveRows` function:

```
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, alignment):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.alignment = alignment #THIS IS THE REAL STORAGE OF MY DATA
        self.setSupportedDragActions(Qt.MoveAction)    


    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.Item
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.alignment.sequences)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.alignment.sequences[index.row()].name)
        return QVariant()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        event.accept()

    def moveRows(self, parent, source_first, source_last, parent2, dest):
        self.beginMoveRows(parent, source_first, source_last, parent2, dest)

        sequences = self.alignment.sequences
        if source_first <= dest:
            new_order = sequences[:source_first] + sequences[source_last+1:dest+1] + sequences[source_first:source_last+1] + sequences[dest+1:]
        else: #TODO what if source_first < dest < source_last
            new_order = sequences[:dest] + sequences[source_first:source_last+1] + sequences[dest:source_first] + sequences[source_last+1:]
        self.alignment.set_sequences(new_order, notify=True)

        print "BEFORE endMoveRows in edit_sequence_list.Model, %s" % self
        self.endMoveRows()
```

The problem is: application, running this Model/View pair first reports the following messages after the drag was performed:

> BEFORE endMoveRows in edit_sequence_list.Model,
>
> (previous line was generated by my print)
>
> QAbstractItemModel::endMoveRows:  Invalid index ( 1493172231 , 0 ) in
>   model Model(0xa973068)

At this point it properly displays drag results and has underlying data in `self.alignment` successfully changed.

But when I close subwindow, displaying this Model/View pair, my application crashes:

> QAbstractEventDispatcher: INTERNAL ERROR, timer ID 0 is too large Aborted

Do you have any idea of what's the cause of these errors and how to fix them? What's wrong with index, why does it have huge first number?

What also seems strange to me is that Model address, printed from python (`0xa8c1bfc`) doesn't match Model address, printed by Qt in error message: `Model(0xa973068)`.

Comment: Well, for a start, you shouldn't have any drag/drop code in your model. The point of the [model/view](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) architecture is for the view to handle all the UI interaction stuff, and the model to just hold (or rather provide an interface to) the data.

Comment: @hackyday `View` just calls `moveRows` of the model upon drop and that's it. It mostly works. :)

Comment: I see, that `dragMoveEvent` in your model is actually superfluous, and not related to the problem then.